# How to wire programmable thermostat that doesn't have an E termimal

Tags: hvac, thermostat, heat-pump

I am trying to replace a manual with programmable thermostat that is missing emergency heat (E) terminal. There are bits and pieces of information I have gathered but am still not clear.

Can I leave off (E)?

Manual thermostat (th3210d1004) terminals:

E|AUX|Y|G|O|L|R|B|C    where L,B are not used

Programmable thermostat (TX1500E) terminals:

G|RH|RC|Y|W|O|B|C

The plan is to wire:
R->RH,RC

E->not used

AUX->W ?

All the other letters are matched. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Your Lux TX1500E thermostat is not made to be used with a Heat Pump system with emergency heat, so it can't be used in your installation.  Lux has an updated model, [TX1500U](http://luxproducts.com/TX1500U.html) that is made for "heat pumps with up to 2-stage heat/1 stage cool".